# SQL Query returning records that have always the same value

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL and doing some practice. I cannot give you the exact scenario because the website I'm practicing on don't want any solution to be found directly on the web so I'll explain the situation in other words. The question I am stuck is using a table XYZ with columns X, Y, and Z. Column X can have duplicates and column Z also. what I need to find is the X's that always have the same value in Z. So

```
X     Y      Z
1     ?      a
1     ?      a
2     ?      b
2     ?      c
3     ?      c
3     ?      a
```

would return me 1 because when X is 1 Z is always a.

My real problem is that I feel I am missing some SQL knowledge in order to achiev this. I would appreciate it if anyone can give me a hint, not a solution but maybe a link to the the SQL knowledge im missing or and brief explanation of the SQL statement that could make me do this.

Otherwise have a nice day.
David.

edit: SELECT X FROM XYZ GROUP BY X HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Z) = 1 worked and I understand it well. Now what I cannot understand is how to add the Z column to the resultset.

Comment: SO is for Questions and **answers** not hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select x, min(z)
from tab
group by x 
having min(z) = max(z) 
-- or
having count(distinct z) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot understanding the group by better. What I still don't understand is how to include a column to the select, without changing the resultset. I understand that if I include that column in the select I will need to include it in the group by also, but when I do the resultset look like it never took the HAVING clause in consideration and returns me 4 times more rows. There is something I realy don't understand with the group by.

Comment: f course you get a different result when you add another column (Y) to the GROUP BY, it's grouping for each distinct combination of both (X and Y) columns. You might use MIN(Y) instead, but it seems like you want all the rows where X = 1. If this is what you want i can add a solution, too. :)

Comment: What I'd like is to have the exact same resultset, but with the value of Z beside X. I get now WHY I got a different result set, thank's alot for your comment, I know its more then just a Q/A but it clarified it and I appreciate alot you took the time to explain why my result set was different (the combination of X and Y)

Answer (score 0):

There are several SQL simple functions that could be used to accomplish this.

`DISTINCT` MSDN http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=SQL.105).aspx

`GROUP BY` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx